# Unable to run Ghost.py on python 3.6.3 (and PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ghost.py

Im trying to use Ghost.py on Python 3.6.3 but I get an error

> ...raise Exception("Ghost.py requires PySide or PyQt4")

I have PyQt5 installed. The message is clear, but in specification on https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py there is information about QT5. Is this the same? How can I make Ghost.py work correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you provide more information, more context? What are you trying to achieve. The more information you give, the more precise the answers will be

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on readme page (dev branch) you need PySide2. PySide2 is a binding for Qt5, like PyQt5, but it's not the same as PyQt5. If you are trying to install version from master branch, you need to install PyQt4 or PySide - bidings for Qt4. Note that PySide doesn't support python3.5+, so you will have to install PyQt4 (and probably compile it from sources or use precompiled wheel).